# How safe is Safe Haskell?

Tags: haskell, sandbox

I was thinking about [Safe Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html) and I wonder how much I can trust it?

---

#### Some fictional scenarios:

1. I am a little hacker writing a programmable game (think [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/)) where I allow others to program their own entities to compete against each other. Most of the time users will run some untrusted programs on private machines. Untrusted code would probably be inspected before running it.
2. I am the programmer of an application that is used by several clients. I provide an api so they can extend the functionality and encourage my users to share their plugins. The user community is small and most of the time there is mutual trust, but occasionally someone is working on a top-secret client project and any dataleaks would prove disastrous.
3. I am ... Google (or Facebook,Yahoo,etc) and want to allow my clients to *script* their email accounts. Scripts are uploaded and are run on my servers. Any access violations would be fatal.

---

#### Given these scenarios:

- would *Safe Haskell* be appropriate to ensure sandboxing and access restriction?
- Should someone in the given situations be able to trust the promises made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, I'd say safe Haskell tries to get roughly where the safe subset of C# is. For your scenarios:

1. Can use safe haskell because you are inspecting code.
2. Cannot really use safe haskell alone to avoid disastrous data leaks.
3. I wouldn't recommend Google or Yahoo relying on safe haskell alone to run untrusted code. For one thing, it doesn't manage excessive resource consumption (CPU,memory,disk) or bottoms (undefined or while true). Use an OS sandbox for that.

A note on undefined: operationally, it stops the function returning a value by throwing an exception, as does the error function. Denotationally, it's considered to be the 'bottom' value. Now, even if safe Haskell disallowed undefined and error, a function could still fail to return, just by looping endlessly. And an endless loop is bottom too. So safe Haskell guarantees type and memory safety but doesn't try to guarantee that functions terminate. Safe Haskell is, of course, Turing complete, so it's not possible in general to prove termination. Furthermore, since out-of-memory throws an exception, functions may terminate with them. Finally, pattern match errors throw exceptions. So safe Haskell cannot eliminate bottoms of any kind and may as well allow explicit undefined and error.

Comment: Could you expand on the "safe Haskell alone" statements? My impression is that **if** I use safe Haskell I will probably also use some sort of sandbox to restrict untrusted code runtime and/or something like free monad dsls for restricting users to a subset of Haskell

Comment: @Florian Safe Haskell is more to prevent people from using functions that are unsafe from a type system point of view, not from a "sandbox" point of view. If you want that, you should write a dsl that you can interpret. Consider looking at free monads, they're pretty awesome for building dsls for that purpose.

Comment: Reason (3) is particularly compelling.

Comment: In google's case: they have a python engine, where (3) is just as relevant, so I guess they use some kind of resource monitoring... so just because the language doesn't support it, it doesn't mean it's not doable.

Comment: @bheklilr *free monads*: yep ... like I said in my comment above ;) Actually I wrote a post about using free monads to compile control programs for some big fat machines I used some time ago. That will be announced when (it's done and) it gets approved by the company building those machines :)

Comment: Just reread your answer. Safe Haskell doesn't handle `undefinded`? What is the reasoning behind that? Sure it can't prevent anyone passing `undefined`s *to* it ... but surely it could prevent `undefined`s *in* safe code?

Answer (score -6):

To my knowledge, safe Haskell is not safe. Someone can use `unsafePerformIO` in a package and manually override the "unsafe" factor. If not, every package that had any dependencies on c programs or system libraries could not be marked safe. (Think about `libgmp.so`, which is linked to by almost everyone's Haskell base packages. For the base packages to be marked safe, this must be somehow getting explicitly marked as safe even though it uses `unsafePerformIO`).

Comment: Safe Haskell should remove `unsafePerformIO` and other unsafe functions. Packages have to be marked as trusted to be imported.

Comment: I am on @JohannesKuhn's side here. Afaik `unsafePerformIO` is one of the reasons *Safe Haskell* exists.

Comment: -1 You can't import `System.IO.Unsafe` in a module compiled with `Safe`. Marking a module as 'trustworthy' can be done, but you wouldn't allow marking a module as such when loading a foreign file.